# Go Package/File Locations

Tags: package, go

From the looks of the go documentation, they make it seem like you have to put code you're working on under your $GOPATH-- is that correct?

I would like to set up a test project in a dir under my ~/Documents, but everytime i run `go install example/newmath` (like in the test example) it says the following--

```
λ MacBook-Air src → go install example/newmath
warning: GOPATH set to GOROOT (/usr/local/go) has no effect
can't load package: package example/newmath: import "example/newmath": cannot find package
```

Does that mean that i need to reset my $GOPATH/$GOROOT? I'm lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to setup `GOROOT` in the common situation. `GOPATH`, OTOH, should be set (**and** exported).

I would recommend to start with

```
   export GOPATH=$HOME
```

Then just put a package having `import  "whatever"` into `$GOPATH/src/whatever`.

You can refine your `GOPATH` to your needs later, when you get used to how things work with the Go build system (`go {build, install}`). One can have even multiple items in `$GOPATH`, but I really don't think it's a concern in the beginning, and sometimes never.